# How to trace the routes to all hosts in a subnet?

Tags: traceroute

I am trying to trace the routes to all live hosts in a subnet. How would one design the command? I've tried the commands below, to no avail. Man pages does not make me any wiser.

```
mtr -c 1 --report 10.10.16.X
mtr -c 1 --report 10.10.16.0/24

traceroute 10.10.16.X
traceroute 10.10.16.0/24
```

Comment: By definition, all hosts in a local subnet can be contacted directly with no routing involved. For a remote subnet, the route would be the same for all addresses in that subnet. traceroute should display the route even for a target that is unallocated or turned off.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing available. Almost always all IPs in same block are using same routes (typical routing works with subnet masks).

In Linux, you can use short script, for example

```
for i in $(seq 1 255); do
 traceroute 10.10.16.$i
done
```

This prints route to each address, and do not include any comparing functions to detect different routes to different addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your command needs some dots and commas

```
for i in $(seq 1 255); do traceroute 10.118.0.$i; done
```

Comment: Why did you copy/paste previous answer? More than 12 years after !